# TIpTCPServer and Client in one application

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7, indy10

I make an application where the client and the server are in the same program. I use Delphi XE7 and components TIpTCPServer / ... Client. But when I try to close the server with the client connected (in the same window), the program stops responding. Perhaps this is something related to multithreading. How to implement a program with a client and server in one application and is this the right approach?

```
procedure TfrmMain.startClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (server.active) then stopServer()
  else startServer();
end;

procedure TfrmMain.startServer();
var
  binding: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  server.bindings.clear();

  try
    server.defaultPort := strToInt(port.text);
    binding := server.bindings.add();
    binding.ip := ip;
    binding.port := strToInt(port.text);

    server.active := true;

    if (server.active) then begin
      addToLog('Server started');
      start.caption := 'Stop';
    end;
  except on e: exception do
    addToLog('Error: ' + e.message + '.');
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.stopServer();
begin
  server.active := false;
  server.bindings.clear();

  if (not(server.active)) then begin
    addToLog('Server stopped');
    start.caption := 'Start';
  end
  else addToLog('Server shutdown error.');
end;

procedure TfrmMain.serverConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  addToLog('New client: ' + aContext.connection.socket.binding.peerIP + '.');

  clients.clear();
  for i := 0 to server.contexts.lockList.count - 1 do begin
    with TIdContext(server.contexts.lockList[i]) do
      clients.items.add(connection.socket.binding.peerIP);
  end;
  server.contexts.unlockList();
end;

procedure TfrmMain.serverDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  addToLog('Client ' + aContext.connection.socket.binding.peerIP + ' disconnected from the server.');
end;

procedure TfrmMain.clientConnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  addToConsole('You connected to server successfully.');
end;

procedure TfrmMain.clientDisconnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  addToConsole('The connection to the server was interrupted.');
end;
```

and connection code:

```
client.host := ip;

try
  client.connect();
except on e: exception do
  addToConsole('Error: ' + e.message);
end;
```

Comment: Please show your actual code. You are likely doing something wrong in how you are using the TCP components together.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I updated the question.

Comment: What is `TIpTCPServer`? Do you mean `TIdTCPServer`?

Comment: @JerryDodge, yes, but, probably, site flip the letter. ;(

Comment: I've never heard of a website automatically changing what someone typed in such a manner, not to mention twice.

Comment: @JerryDodge, now you understand how surprised I was.

Comment: This site did not *flip the letter*. You typed it wrong. If this site *flipped letters* while people typed, it would be a bug that would have broken things long ago and been reported, which it has not been. And you still have not edited your post to fix the typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a number of issues with this code.

- How are `addToLog()` and `addToConsole()` implemented?  Are they thread-safe?  Remember that `TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component, its events are fired in the context of worker threads, not the main UI thread, so any access to the UI, shared variables, etc must be synchronized.
- What is `clients`?  Is it is a UI control?  You need to sync access to it so you don't corrupt its content when multiple threads try to access it at the same time.
- Your use of the `TIdTCPServer.Contexts` property is not adequately protected from exceptions.  You need a `try..finally` block so you can call `Contexts.UnlockList()` safely.
- More importantly, you are calling `Contexts.LockList()` *too many times* in your `serverConnect()` loop (this is the root cause of your problem).  `LockList()` returns a `TIdContextList` object.  Inside your loop, you should be accessing that list's `Items[]` property instead of calling `LockList()` again.  Because you do not have a matching `UnlockList()` for each `LockList()`, once a client connects to your server, the `Contexts` list becomes deadlocked, and can no longer be accessed once `serverConnect()` exits, which includes when clients connect/disconnect, and during `TIdTCPServer` shutdown (such as in your case).
- `serverDisconnect()` is not removing any items from `clients`. `serverConnect()` should not be resetting `clients` at all.  It should add only the calling `TIdContext` to `clients`, and then `serverDisconnect()` should remove that same `TIdContext` from `clients` later.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.addToConsole(const AMsg: string);
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      // add AMsg to console ...
    end
  );
end;

procedure TfrmMain.addToLog(const AMsg: string);
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      // add AMsg to log ...
    end
  );
end;

procedure TfrmMain.startClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if server.Active then
    stopServer()
  else
    startServer();
end;

procedure TfrmMain.startServer();
var
  binding: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  server.Bindings.Clear();

  try
    server.DefaultPort := StrToInt(port.Text);
    binding := server.Bindings.Add();
    binding.IP := ip;
    binding.Port := StrToInt(port.Text);

    server.Active := True;

    addToLog('Server started');
    start.Caption := 'Stop';
  except
    on e: Exception do
      addToLog('Error: ' + e.message + '.');
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.stopServer();
begin
  try
    server.Active := False;
    server.Bindings.Clear();

    addToLog('Server stopped');
    start.Caption := 'Start';
  except
    on e: Exception do
      addToLog('Server shutdown error.');
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.serverConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  PeerIP: string;
begin
  PeerIP := AContext.Binding.PeerIP;
  addToLog('New client: ' + PeerIP + '.');

  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    {
    var
      i: integer;
      list: TIdContextList;
    }
    begin
      {
      clients.clear();
      list := server.Contexts.LockList;
      try
        for i := 0 to list.count - 1 do begin
          clients.Items.Add(TIdContext(list[i]).Binding.PeerIP);
        end;
      finally
        list.UnlockList();
      end;
      }

      // I'm assuming clients is a UI control whose Items property
      // is a TStrings object.  If not, adjust this code as needed...
      clients.Items.AddObject(PeerIP, AContext);
    end;
  );
end;

procedure TfrmMain.serverDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  addToLog('Client ' + AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ' disconnected from the server.');

  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      i: Integer;
    begin
      // I'm assuming clients is a UI control whose Items property
      // is a TStrings object.  If not, adjust this code as needed...
      i := clients.Items.IndexOfObject(AContext);
      if i <> -1 then
        clients.Items.Delete(i);
    end
  );
end;

procedure TfrmMain.clientConnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  addToConsole('You connected to server successfully.');
end;

procedure TfrmMain.clientDisconnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  addToConsole('The connection to the server was interrupted.');
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, you wrote a lot of things that I did not know. Will your code be secure if `addToLog` and` addToConsole` add data to the form (`TMemo`)?

Comment: Thanks again. At the moment everything is working, and I think the problem was in my incorrect work with the component. In particular, multithreading.

Comment: @nup The use of `TThread.Queue()` ensures that all access to UI controls is performed only in the context of the UI thread, not in the context of the server threads. And yes, your problem was misusing the `Contexts` list in particular, by keeping it locked when you were done accessing it